# Haskell data structure find method

Tags: haskell, data-structures

As I'm constructing my data structure I found an issue that I'm having trouble solving it. My data structure "Structure" is String and a list of subStructures.

The issue is in the "lookFor" method below, that is supposed to look for a subStructure named "a" in (Structure b xs) and return it. If not on "b"'s list (xs), it should continue looking in each xs element's list and so on. If not found it should do nothing.

My idea was recursion, and for that, I thought "map lookFor xs" in case it hasn't found the Structure named "a".

Ghci says "Couldn't match expected type Structure with actual type [Structure]"
Which I understand, because after all map returns a list of elements and not an element.

```
data Structure = Structure String [Structure]

name :: Structure -> String
name (Structure a xs) = a

subStrcts :: Structure -> [String]
subStrcts (Structure a []) = []
subStrcts (Structure a xs) = [name x | x <- xs]

lookFor :: String -> Structure -> Structure
lookFor a (Structure b xs) 
    | elem (elemIndex a (subStrcts (Structure b xs))) [0..] = xs !! (fromJust (elemIndex a (subStrcts (Structure b xs))))
    | otherwise = map (lookFor a) xs
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `lookFor` return a `Maybe Structure`?

Comment: Furthermore is *breadth-first* search a requirement, or is any search strategy sufficient?

Comment: Yes, it should be a breadth-first. Can you please elaborate on the Maybe Structure part? I'm new to this language and I'm still in an adaptation period. Sorry and thank you @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: well you do not know if you will find a `Structure` that matches the query, right? In case you do not find one, you can not simply return `null` (well Haskell has an `undefined`, but it is usually better not to use that). In that case you can use a `Maybe Structure`. A `Maybe a`, has two possible values `Nothing` (i.e. the query did not give a result), or `Just x` with `x` the result.

Comment: Right, sure it makes sense. However, I'm not aware how can I implement it in lookFor :\ @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Is your `Structure` just a [`RoseTree String`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Algebraic_data_type#Rose_tree)?

Comment: Yes it is @user28434

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution is:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Foldable

data Structure = Structure String [Structure]
               deriving Show

lookFor :: String -> Structure -> Maybe Structure
lookFor a s@(Structure b xs)
   | a == b    = Just s
   | otherwise = asum (map (lookFor a) xs)
```

Above, `map (lookFor a) xs` searches `a` in the substructures. This produces a `[Maybe Structure]`, on which we use `asum` to take the first `Just _` value, so that we can return it. (If no such value is found, `asum` returns `Nothing`.)

If you don't want to exploit `asum` from the libraries, defining it is a nice beginner exercise.

Answer (score 0):

As a recursive structure, you need to set a base case. In your example, this happens when you have exhausted all structures in your list.

As @WillemVanOnsem, it's better to return a `Maybe Structure`, as it is possible for the `lookFor` function not to find the Structure

```
import Data.List (elemIndex)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust, isJust)

data Structure = Structure String [Structure]

name :: Structure -> String
name (Structure a xs) = a

subStrcts :: Structure -> [String]
subStrcts (Structure a []) = []
subStrcts (Structure a xs) = [name x | x <- xs]

lookFor :: String -> Structure -> Maybe Structure
lookFor a (Structure b xs) 
    | null xs = Nothing
    | isJust maybeIndex = fmap (xs !!) maybeIndex
    | otherwise = lookFor a (Structure (name (head xs)) (tail xs))
    where maybeIndex = elemIndex a (subStrcts (Structure b xs))
```